# Auto-generated EF Core Context and Entities (.efm, .edps, and .view files )

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have inherited a .Net Core project that uses EF Core, and I noticed that the database context as well as all entity classes are auto-generated using some sort of a tool, so I assume that a database-first approach was used. However, I am not able to figure out which tool that was. My suspicion is that it's a devart product called Entity Developer, but I cannot be 100% certain, and would appreciate any help!

I noticed that there is a .efml file, an .edps file. and a Diagram.view file. The database context and the entities have this text in the top section:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This is auto-generated code.
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This code was generated by Entity Developer tool using EF Core template.
// Code is generated on: 2019-09-15 9:52:34 AM
//
// Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
// the code is regenerated.
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So my question is: which tool is that? Is there another tool called Entity Framework out there that anybody knows about?

Comment: Um, did you try googling for "Entity Developer Tool" (the tool that the comments say auto-genned the code). If I do that, I get www.devart.com/entitydeveloper. You might also want to look at the reverse POCO tool

Comment: I believe it is standard to just scaffold the database. 
The "old" way of using a tool, has become a little redundant in my opinion. 

https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/EFCore-Database-First-NET-Core.html
this guide isn't completely useless.

Comment: @Flydog57 yes, obviously, I did google that, and this is how I came to the same conclusion that it's a devart product. I just needed to confirm because the name is a bit too generic 'Entity Developer tool' and the auto-generated comment is not very indicative. Anyway, thanks for taking the time to comment.

Comment: I've used the Reverse POCO tool before and loved it. Unfortunately, the author has decided to charge for the latest version (compatible with EF Core). I think it's worth it, but, when there's money involved, selling a tool for internal use gets much more complicated. https://reversepoco.co.uk/

Comment: The free devart version generate a maximum of 10 entities per model... I guess I either have to get the paid version or just implement future entities manually..